# Why RESTful web service choose XML instead of JSON if we give both in produces list?

Tags: java, json, web-services, cxf

I have a RESTful web service that produces both XML and JSON. But when I give both in produces list such as

```
@Produces({"application/json","application/xml"})
```

It only produces XML when I run it in a browser. So my question does XML is default or high priority than the other ?

Comment: Try using any API client tool and define Accept header to be application JSON and It will return JSON, I think when you call from the browser it doesn't specify Accept header I think this is the reason.

Comment: Ok I tried postman with chrome and it worked with XML when I provide Accept key as XML in Header. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `application/xml` since I doubt that you need that and it will return JSON as response even on your browser, but if you really need that `application/xml` I suggest you to test your REST API using REST Client such as Postman or just simple curl and specify on your header request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Yes it worked in that way. But if i remove application/xml then that means my service client won't able to consume XML if it wants right ?

Comment: Yes, browser is not good media to test your REST API, so I suggest to use REST Client such as Postman or wathever you like and you can control what kind of response that you want.